# Update a set of rows of a table having no primary key

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I want to update set of rows using ODP.net. 
I want to get list of employees based on increasing asscending order of PRIORITY and update PRIORITY column with value 1 and increment by 1.
I tried below approach and it gives error "Dynamic SQL generation failed. No key information found"

```
StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPT ='" + dept + "' ORDER BY PRIORITY";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(StrQuery, ora);
OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(dt);
intNpriority = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["PRIORITY"] = intNpriority;
    intNpriority = intNpriority + 1;
}
da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
da.Update(dt);
```

The table has no primary key and i cannot add one now. Can i add custom update query and how? Is there anyalternative way to acheive same?

table strucure:

```
column name   |  (data type)
Employee_name |  (varchar2)
dept          |  (varchar2)
PRIORITY      | (NUMBER)
```

Comment: Whenever you have a question like this, state the existing data structure (column names and data types, whether they are nullable etc.), provide a few sample rows, and show the desired output. Don't ask us to read your code (which you yourself admit is NOT DOING what you want it to do) and guess what's behind all this.

Comment: Can you use the Oracle ROWID column?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent two days to find some way to workaround.
Lucky that I could get it done.
The idea is to add a dump primary key in the DataTable, this new dump column does not affect the real database table.
Here's my code sample

Dim currentRow = m_DataTable.Rows(m_RowPosition)
Dim tmpRows() As DataRow = {currentRow}

```
        Dim cmdBuilder As OracleCommandBuilder = New OracleCommandBuilder(m_Adapter)
        
        **If m_DataTable.PrimaryKey.Count = 0 Then
            m_DataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("_ID_", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
            m_DataTable.Columns("_ID_").Unique = True
        End If**

        m_Adapter.Update(tmpRows)
```

Note: The currentRow  is the row is being edited .
Please consider carefully to apply this tip because it might update all data of table.
It's suitable for case your table has only one row ( some kind of configuration data )